# Cuando referenciar y cuando instanciar

Tags: java, poo

tengo una duda, cual es la diferencia entre estas 2 formas de almacenar un objeto?
En esta primera forma creo un objeto y le asigno otro que es resultado de una busqueda en la base de datos:

```
User user = new User();
user = userService.findById(idUser);
```

y esta otra forma:

```
User user = userService.findById(idUser);
```

se sobre lo que es POO y que es instanciar y todo eso, pero no entiendo bien cual seria la diferencia entre crear un objeto y asignarle un valor con el de referenciar un objeto (como un tipo) y asignarle un valor, a mi parecer esta segunda seria la mejor opción pero no se si estoy en lo correcto, si alguien pudiera explicármelo bien se lo agradecería. 
Gracias.

Comment: Si creas un objeto para que asignarle luego otro valor? La creación inicial se pierde innecesariamente

Comment: Estas haciendo justamente una pregunta, que demuestra que no sabes lo que POO.

Comment: gbianchi tengo mis dudas, he programado mas en js y pasar a java es otra cosa y conceptos específicos como instanciar y referenciar, no me quedan muy claros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La primera forma es incorrecta porque es un desperdicio de recursos (tiempo y memoria).

Analicémoslo:

```
User user = new User();
```

En esa línea se hacen 3 operaciones:

1. Se declara una variable de tipo User.
2. Se crea una instancia de la clase User, llamando al constructor.
3. Se asigna la instancia recién creada a la variable. Es decir, la variable user apunta a un objeto de la clase User.

```
user = userService.findById(idUser);
```

En esta línea ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Se llama a un método que, dado un identificador, devuelve una instancia de la clase User.
2. Una vez obtenida la instancia, se almacena en la variable user. Si la variable user apuntaba ya a otra instancia, la nueva sustituye a la antigua. Si la antigua no está siendo apuntada por ningún otra variable (lo cual es así, en este caso), será destruida por el recolector de basura.

Por tanto la primera línea hace cosas que no son necesarias.

En el segundo caso tenemos

```
User user = userService.findById(idUser);
```

Lo cual es más eficiente: se crea una variable de tipo User y se le asigna la instancia que el método `findById` genera y devuelve.

Comment: En la segunda parte en el punto 2 indicas que si la variable user apuntaba ya a otra instancia, esta sera reemplazada por la nueva, pero al ser User user = userService.findById(idUser); entiendo que no estoy creando una instancia, si no que estoy creando una variable user de tipo User, pero esto no quiere decir que se esta creando un nuevo objeto, estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: salvo que findbyuser devuelva una copia.. ;) en ese caso si estas creando un nuevo objeto.. y termino de marear a Hugo...

Comment: jajaja, ya lo entendi @gbianchi

Comment: He añadido la explicación del segundo caso para aclararlo

Answer (score 9):

A ver.. esto es un problema de concepto

Toda variable (y voy a hablar casi agnosticamente) es un puntero (si el lenguaje se lo permite) o es directamente el valor.

En este caso, en java, esa variable que vos definis, al declararla de tipo object (porque user seguro es una clase, y toda clase hereda de tipo object) es un puntero. El problema, es que mas alla que sepa que tipo de puntero es, necesitas decirle, a quien apunta.

Tu primera version:

```
User user = new User();
user = userService.findById(idUser);
```

Le dice:

```
Crea la variable user de tipo User, y apuntalo a una nueva instancia de la clase User
Ahora agarra la variable user y hacela apuntar al objeto User que devuelve userService.findById(idUser)
```

O sea.. estas creando un objeto en memoria que no vas a usar, para despues asignarle otro valor.

Obviamente, todo esto funciona.. gastaste espacio de memoria para crear ese objeto (y el puntero) y no lo usaste, pero al final el GC (garbage collector) lo va a rescatar.

La segunda version de tu codigo, hace algo mas logico...

Vos queres la variable.. y ya sabes que va a tener.. entonces que mejor que pasarle directemente eso?

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, si eso es lo que yo pensaba, pero no lo tenia muy claro y que hay por ejemplo con los tipos List<User> users , si lo uso asi estaria bien? o hay que instanciarlo? List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(); en este punto tambien me queda la misma duda XD

Comment: es el mismo caso. o le pasa una lista<user> existente, o creas una vacia si la necesitas vacia.

Comment: le pasaría una lista ya existente, claro, ya entendí, al ser algo que ya existe, no tengo por que crear un objeto nuevo, puedo crear una variable referenciando al tipo que deseo, pero si voy a necesitar un objeto vació para manipularlo por sus getters y setters, ahí si tengo que instanciar un objeto nuevo, estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: no. nuevo si queres que sea nuevo. Si ya existe podes usar el que existe. La variable es solo un puntero para acceder al objeto. el tema es a que objeto queres acceder.